# Need Help with a Trigger for preventing a circular reference on a table

Tags: sql-server-2005, constraints, circular-reference

We currently have a table that looks like this:

```
ChildId    |  ParentID
------------------
1          | NULL
2          | NULL
3          | 1
4          | 3
```

Can anyone help me come up with a constraint/trigger that would prevent a circular reference from being inserted or updated into the table?

Thanks

Comment: I've only asked a couple of questions which is why it's so low.
I haven't logged on in a bit as well so i'll probably go through the list of questions i've previously asked and mark some of them as answered. That should bring it up right?

Comment: We need more information.  What do you mean by a circular reference?  Right now 1->3->4 and then it ends.  So what are you trying to do?

Comment: well it doesn't end with 4.. But even with the example i posted lets say i updated ChildId 1 to have a parentId of 2, ChildId 2 to have parent id of 3, and ChildId 3 to have a parentID of 1. This would be a scenario where a circular reference would occur. An easier scenario would be to update Child 1 to have a parent of 3.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a [trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799(SQL.90).aspx).